# Adjust the position of each text to the top center of its grouped vertical bar plot columns in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

By the code below, I generate a grouped bar plot below:

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c("Mr.A","Mr.B"), Cats = c(3,4), Dogs = c(1,2))
data.m <- melt(df, id.vars='Person')

ggplot(data.m, aes(Person, value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = Person, y = value, label=value), 
    position = position_dodge(width=1),
    # position = 'dodge', 
    # hjust=-1, 
    vjust=-0.25) +
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Now my question is how could we adjust the text in the middle of each bar column (as the arrows shown in the figure above), I tried by paramters: `position=position_dodge(width=1)`, `position='dodge'`, `hjust=-1` and `hjust=1`, it seems not working. Someone could help? Thanks.

**Reference:**

[Aligning geom_text in grouped dodged barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174667/aligning-geom-text-in-grouped-dodged-barplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `group=variable` in `geom_text`.

```r
ggplot(data.m, aes(Person, value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = Person, y = value, label=value, group = variable), 
    position = position_dodge(width=0.5),
    # position = 'dodge', 
    # hjust=-1, 
    vjust=-0.25) +
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]